# Ubuntu with Apache - HTTP times out but HTTPS works

Tags: apache2, 22.04

I have a dedicated server running Ubuntu version 22.04 which is using Apache 2.4.52.

I have added a website and installed an https certificate via LetsEncrypt.

Whenever I try to go to the http:// domain the website does not respond with "This site can’t be reached mysite.org took too long to respond." however the https:// does work and displays my website.

A copy of my websites .conf file is below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5002/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5002/
    ServerAdmin  webmaster@localhost
    ServerName mysite.org
    ServerAlias www.mysite.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.org
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.mysite.org [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =mysite.org
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

[Running wget via the terminal on the server results in a timeout as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvK2H.png)

Thanks for any ideas as I'm a newbie to all of this :)

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 is the 2021-October release; adding 9 months to October tells you when it reaches EOL even if you missed the warning notices (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/ posted ~six weeks prior to EOL)   If you don't like *release-upgrading* every 6-9 months, stick to LTS releases of Ubuntu (*having 5 years instead of 9 months of support, with the option to further extend the support via ESM use too*)